# How to keep calculating even after equal buttons

Tags: java

I recently made a calculator and everything is working fine except for the equal button. While it is outputting the right answer, I would like to keep using operator even after pressing equals. How can I do that?

```
if(e.getSource() == btnEquals) {     
            num2 = 0;
            char operator2 = 's';
            try {
                display.append("=" + "\n");
                for ( String line : display.getText().split("\\n")) {
                    char operator1 = line.charAt(line.length()-1);
                    num1 = Double.parseDouble(line.substring(0, line.length()-1));
                    if (operator2 == 's') {
                        num2 = num1;
                        operator2 = operator1;
                    } else if (operator2 == '+') {
                        num2 = num2 + num1;
                        operator2 = operator1;
                    } else if (operator2 == '-') {
                        num2 = num2 - num1;
                        operator2 = operator1;
                    } else if (operator2 == '*') {
                        num2 = num2 * num1;
                        operator2 = operator1;
                    } else if (operator2 == '/') {
                        num2 = num2 / num1;
                        operator2 = operator1;     
                    }
                }

            } catch (NumberFormatException a) {
                display.setText("Error: Consecutive Operators " + " (=) " + " or no input" + "\n");
             return;
            }

            display.setText(display.getText() + num2);

        }
    }
```

Comment: To get to the current solution we need a little more information, specifically where this comparision is done (some event listener callback, I assume) and what you specifically mean with "keep using". Does the program terminate or freeze?

Answer (score 1):

When you press the button (I assume it is a Swing JButton) all the work is done in a specific thread of execution which is called `event dispatch thread`. As the name implies it is not the right thread for doing the heavy lifting, i.e. your current work. While you are using it it can't dispatch events for other GUI elements so you can't use any other elements.

So you need to put your business work into an extra thread and thus deal with concurrency in Swing. You can read about it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap it with `while(True)` statement and will run till the exit.